# api 20+ only allows simple 1d allocations to be used with bind renderscript

Tags: bind, allocation, renderscript

I develop an application which goal is to calculate the mean of the grayscale on each column. Here is my code:

```
mInputAllocation=Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRs, mBitmapIn.MipMapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
mOutputAllocation=Allocation.createSized(mRs, Element.I32, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
mScript.bind_gInPixels(mInputAllocation);
mScript.bind_gResult(mOutputAllocation);
mScript.invoke_filter();
```

And in myscript.rs I have:

```
int sum;
int32_t *gResult;
const uchar4 *gInPIxels;
void root(const uint32_t *v_in, int_32 *v_out, uint32_t x, uint32_t y){
for(int i=0;i<mImageWidth;i++){
sum=sum+gray;}
gResult[*v_out]=sum;}

void filter(){
rsForEach(gScript, gIn, gOut);}
```

I got this exception while executing the application on my phone:
API20+ only allows simple 1D allocations to be used with bind.

Answer (score 0):

I am definitely missing something from myscript.rs, because I see references to "gray", but no actual definition. You also seem to be using *v_out as an index, but that is really not what it is intended for. As far as accessing data at a different x/y coordinate, you would be best off using rsSetElementAt_int(). Take a look at that function in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_allocation_data.html#android_rs:rsSetElementAt.

Comment: Excuse me, i didn t post all my code, because i thought there was no need. Here is how i get gray, just after for:    float f4=rsUnpackColor8888(rsGetElementAt_uchar4(gInPixels, i*mImageWidth, v_in);          float gray =(dot(f4.rgb, gConv))/mImageWidth,

Comment: gConv wwhich i define as a script global as const float3 gconv={0.2126f, 0.7152f, 0.0722f}

Comment: Right, so it seems like you are misusing v_in (and v_out). You really should be using x and y if you want to index particular locations. Your rsGetElementAt_uchar4() is doing i*mImageWidth for the x coordinate to look at, and the cell's input as the y coordinate. If you really want to get the column values, you will want to do it more like rsGetElementAt_uchar4(gInPixels, x, i * y), assuming you are looping over the height using i.

Comment: but i don t want to use x and y because i need to calculate the mean of gray of each columnn